# SoundPool. On weak devices, application crashes due to a greater number of sounds

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I have about 200 sounds. Every sound no more than 30Kb. I use to load in OnGreate

```
Sound = loadSound ("sound.ogg");
```

and the method

```
private int loadSound (String fileName) {
         AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
         try {
             afd = mAssetManager.openFd (fileName);
         } Catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace ();
             return -1;
         }
         return mSoundPool.load (afd, 1);
     }
```

On weak devices, application crashes due to a greater number of sounds. Too long "loading". how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i understand that you want to preload all the sounds to speed up playing them, but that slows down loading the application during "onCreate" so much that the application may "crash".  you can get the best of both options by using a cache manager to pre-load the sounds in a background thread while still ensure they are available when they are needed. even on a week device, you should not have any trouble loading the sounds since it should be less than 6MB total memory consumed. something like this should do:

```
public class SoundCache {
    private HashMap<String, Integer> sounds = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    public int getSound(String fileName){
        Integer sound = cache.get(fileName);
        if(sound == null){
            sound = loadSound(fileName);
            cache.put(fileName, sound);
        }
        return sound;
    }

    public void preload(final String... fileNames){
        new Thread(){
            for(String fileName : fileNames){
                getSound(fileName);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

then in your existing application code. you instead of this:

```
public class YourExistingClass{
    private int sound1;
    private int sound2;
    ...
    public void onCreate(){
        ...
        sound1 = loadSound("sound1.ogg");
        sound2 = loadSound("sound2.ogg");
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void handleEvent1(){
        ...
        play(sound1);
        ...
    }
}
```

do something like this:

```
public class YourExistingClass{
    private SoundCache soundCache  = new SoundCache();
    private String sound1 = "sound1.ogg";
    private String sound2 = "sound2.ogg";
    ...
    public void onCreate(){
        ...
        soundCache.preload(sound1,sound2
        ...
        );
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void handleEvent1(){
        ...
        play(soundCache.getSound(sound1));
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a memory cache to store your sounds similar to how this bitmap example [from the android developer page](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) does it.

Just swap out Bitmap types with Sound types and you should be able to make a memory cache of sounds using a fraction of the available device memory. That way, you won't ever crash from allocating too much memory.

If you return null after searching for your Sound in the cache, you should'll have to load it from disk.